# How to set the DNS server use for a VPN connection

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vpn, dns, url

I have Windows XP and I connect to a VPN. However for some reason when I'm connected the system is using broken DNS from work. That means I can only go to websites by IP address.

I would like to bypass that limitation by making the system use custom DNS.

How could I do that and which DNS addresses should I use?

Comment: What VPN clinet do you use?

Comment: @Dave M nx-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the work DNS broken when you are on their network?  If not then that might not be your problem.  If it is Google and OpenDNS both offer public DNS servers which may work for you.

If you already have set the DNS servers manually, that may cause problems if you can't reach them from your work address.  ISPs commonly restrict access to the DNS servers they specify for their clients.

I have encountered Malware which resets the DNS servers.  When repairing this problem I found out the there are service specific registry entries for DNS servers.  Fortunately, it wasn't one of my systems.